# Как сжать файл .bmp до нужного размера?

Tags: оптимизация, графика, сжатие, bmp

Исходный размер файла 139 523 кб, требуется сжать файл, не изменяя размера изображения до 102 000 кб. Пробовал различные оптимизаторы, но везде сжимает или под 17 000 кб или качество сильно страдает и все равно не попадает под нужный размер. Никак не могу найти пригодный инструмент для этого.

Comment: А файлы bmp традиционно хранят изображения без сжатия или индексированные. По сути - массив пикселей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это BMP, он жмётся только изменением количества цветов. А PNG или JPG, в крайнем случае TIFF, можно сжимать и оптимизировать.